# Fortran code multidimensional array

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am converting an old fortran code to java but I am stuck with following line:

```
PARAMETER (MAXC=15)
REAL CKV(MAXC,MAXC)

DATA (CKV( 1,J),J= 2,15)/10*0.,.45,.02,.12,.08/
DATA (CKV( 2,J),J= 3,15)/ 9*0.,.45,.06,.15,.07/
```

Can someone explain the above last two lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PARAMETER (MAXC=15)
```

This declares `MAXC` a parameter (constant) and assign the value 15.

```
REAL CKV(MAXC,MAXC)
```

This is a declaration of the floating point (single precision) array `CKV` of dimensions `(MAXC,MAXC)`

```
DATA (CKV( 1,J),J= 2,15)/10*0.,.45,.02,.12,.08/
DATA (CKV( 2,J),J= 3,15)/ 9*0.,.45,.06,.15,.07/
```

This statement assigns initial values to `CKV` (at least to some elements). `10*0.` means "take 10 times the 0.".

To clarify my answer (as requested in the comment):

`(CKV( 1,J),J= 2,15)` means "initialize the array subsection `CKV( 1,2:15)`", i.e. 14 elements. This matches the 14 elements on the right-hand-side (10x`0.`, `.45`,`.02`,`.12`,`.08`).

The second implicit loop starts at `3`, so only 13 elements are assigned. Therefore, it is just `9*0.`.

Comment: You reply partially ans my Q. 

As i understand the first part of above line means CKV(1,2) and CKV(1,15) 
then why there are 5 values (10*0. , .45,   .02,      .12,      .08) to the right of it.